# What is the easiest way to classify text and photos in a website by machine learning algorithms?

Tags: web, machine-learning

I am working on a social website, where everyone can share their ideas. So I want to classify the text and photos that users share, to not allow people to share pornographic, political, and impolitic (bad language) contents.

So here I should use machine learning algorithms to do this, I searched about Firebase but I found that Firebase ML kit is only for Android and IOS not for web. I searched about Google Cloud and AWS but they require credit card information for registration. I am in a country where I can’t use credit card for these services, even our country name is not in their list.

So I am trying to find a free, easy, and fast way to use machine learning algorithms to classify text and photos in my website.

I use MySQL and Laravel for backend, and Vue for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) package has a really good platform independent support available for Machine Learning algorithms. I have used it in python environment. During my time tinkering with it, I understood that it is used as an api therefore it can be used in different platforms. Try it out.

All the best! :)